# Why is the square root of a number which is drawn from an exponetial distribution, Rayleigh distributed?

Tags: rayleigh-distribution

If we have a number $X\sim f(x|\lambda)$ where
$$f(x|\lambda) = \lambda e^{\lambda x}, x \geq 0$$
then $\sqrt{X} \sim r(y|\sigma)$ where
$$r(y|\sigma) = \frac{y}{\sigma^{2}} e^{-y^{2} /(2 \sigma^{2})}, y \geq 0$$
which is the Rayleigh distribution. Why is this the case? It is easy to prove this mathematically with the transformation technique, as shown [here](http://www.math.wm.edu/%7Eleemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/ExponentialRayleigh.pdf), but I'd like to have a more intuitive understanding on why this arises.

For example the emergence of the Rayleigh distribution can be readily explained by considering the absolute value of two normally, uncorrelated vector components.

Comment: Doesn't your last remark answer your question?

Comment: I feel the two must be related, and perhaps my question is somewhat circular. I suppose then I am asking: $\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$, which implies that $a^{2} + b^{2}$ must belong to an exponential distribution.

Comment: The sum of squares of two iid zero-mean Normal variates has an exponential distribution.

Comment: As far as I am concerned it is all about the densities.  $e^{-x^2/2}$ and similar functions are difficult to integrate, while $e^{-x}$ is easy and $xe^{-x^2/2}$ is not much harder.  So the question becomes what something with a density proportional to $xe^{-x^2/2}$ might represent.  There are at least two answers: (a) take the square root of a suitable exponential distribution using a change of variable, or (b) take a 2D polar version of a standard normal with uniformly distributed angle, in effect multiplying the normal density by $2\pi x$ and then standardising.